# How to stop the Service when come back from Activity in android?

Tags: java, android

I have created the Service in android and it has running when go to the MapActivity, if i come back from MapActivity using back button, i want to stop the service. how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Context.stopService(serviceObject);` to stop service from an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
 //stop your Service here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you using the device backbutton for navigate to previous class , then use write:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
 //stop your Service here
}
```

If you used custom back button for navigate to previous class, then maintain static boolean variable in second class.

```
Second class: static boolean navigate = false;
when you click the custom back button in second class, then  make boolean as true;

now, in first class check the value for true: 
if it is ture , then stop the service by using Context.stopService(serviceObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override

void onDestroy
{
unbindService(ServiceConnection c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) which I bind to in activitys' onStart() and unbind from in onStop(). I bind using Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE, so that the service stops automatically when no activity is bound to it. It is a convenient way of letting more than one activity use the service and of passing data from activity to the service through an IBinder interface